# proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine() returns empty string when I am going to run a p4 (Perforce) command from my c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, stdout, stdin, perforce

I have a working code in C# (of course in another machine) which after migration, it does not anymore. The code runs a command toward a perforce server in command prompt and reads the output looking for a specific string. the code is:

```
string result="";
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

            //Start the process
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
            //Attach output for reading
            System.IO.StreamReader sOut = proc.StandardOutput;
            System.IO.StreamWriter sIn = proc.StandardInput;

            sIn.WriteLine(@"p4 changelists -m 1 -s submitted //<SOME_PATH_HERE>");
            proc.WaitForExit(500);
            sIn.WriteLine("EXIT");

            while((result=sOut.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(result != "")
                {
                    if(result.Substring(0, 6) == "Change")
                    {
                        //get Changelist number
                        result = result.Substring(7, 6);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if((result == "") || (result == null))  //if perforce goes down
            {
```

the problem is when i issue some cmd.exe wellknown commands such as DIR and ... I can see the out put line by line in my result variable but for this special command of p4 the result string is empty.

I googled my problem and the closest thing that might be related was something to do with CASPOL !?

I don't have any idea of what it is exaclty and how can I get rid of it.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with C# to be able to debug the `RedirectStandardError` part of your code, but *usually* if you're scripting a p4 command and it appears to fail silently it means you're not capturing stderr.

I can see your code capturing stdout explicitly; does it maybe need to do something like this?

```
System.IO.StreamReader sErr = proc.StandardError;
...
while((result=sErr.ReadLine()) != null)
   ...
```

I notice that your code doesn't provide any connection information, so my guess as to why it's failing after migration is that it was dependent on authentication/connection settings in the old machine's environment (like valid values for `P4USER` and `P4PORT` and a `P4TICKETS` file with a valid authentication ticket).  If you're able to get stderr from the failing command it will give you more information (like "can't connect to server" or "authentication failed" or "user unknown").

Comment: Actually I have provided the connection credentials and other stuff previousley some where else in the code. No matter connected or not Ibwould expect some errir messages as I read the output line by line. The problem is that the result string is empty even for the connection error messages

Comment: As I said, if you're not seeing an error message it usually means that you're not looking at stderr.  As a cheap workaround you could add the `-s` global flag, which tells `p4` to print everything to stdout with tags rather than directing info to stdout and errors to stderr.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I got the error in stderr saying that it cannot write p4ticket file into its path. I grant the write permisson to the path at it working now. Thanks a bunch dude